# Регулярные выражения для выборки слов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, есть строка

```
select b.no as no, b.number_car as number_car from car as b where a.no = 2
```

Как можно вырезать слова после as, то есть чтобы получилось no и number_car в итоге. Никак не могу составить регулярное выражение для этого да и split тоже не очень помогает. 
Пытался отбросить часть from car as b where a.no = 2, все равно не выходит, то есть не ищет as.
Может кто знает?

Comment: т.е. вам нужны только те as которые до from, а после from не нужны ? Если так и если бы это были pcre регурлярки, я бы сказал, что наверняка потребуется `\G` т.е. точка последнего захвата, но вот есть ли она в java дилекте ... еще может помочь сверхжадный захват всего от from до конца строки в другую группу

Comment: ему нужны все имена колонок

Comment: Да, именно as до form, то есть мне это надо, чтобы выцепить название столбцов, я то вроде как придумал, то это такое извращенство с обрезанием строк заменами и тд.

Comment: @DaysLikeThis да, именно. Мне нужно получит название колонок. Сам регулярку составить не могу(((

Comment: Вот так https://regex101.com/r/KIjYkD/3 например, совпадения в первой группе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65111/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно найти все вхождения слов после целого слова `as`, но только до первого вхождения слова `from`.

Тут можно воспользоваться *tempered greedy token*, умеренно-жадной конструкцией типа `(?:(?!<ДО_КАКОГО_ШАБЛОНА_ИЩЕМ>).)*?`, а также начинать поиск с начала строки и только после удачного совпадения.

```
String regex = "\\G(?:(?!\\bfrom\\b).)*?\\bas\\s+(\\w+)";
String string = "select b.no as no, b.number_car as number_car from car as b where a.no = 2";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
// => [no, number_car]
```

[См. Java-демо](https://ideone.com/O4o9LF)

**ПОДРОБНОСТИ**

- `\G` - начало строки или конец предыдущего совпадения
- `(?:(?!\bfrom\b).)*?` - любой символ (кроме перевода строки, если не используется `Pattern.DOTALL`), 0 и более раз, как можно меньше, но только если он не является первым символом последовательности `from` как целого слова
- `\bas\s+` - целое слово `as`  (`\b` - граница слова) и 1+ пробельных символов (`\s+`)
- `(\w+)` - Группа 1: один и более цифр, букв или `_`.

Comment: Вот здорово, спасибо большое за РВ и за описание подробное. Щас все выбирается как положено:) Нужно будет заняться изучением регулярных выражений